# Proof $p(a|b) = p(a) \implies p(a|b,c) = p(a|c)$ with concrete example

Tags: probability, random-variables

We got an assignment to proof following statement:

$p(a|b)=p(a) \implies p(a|b,c)=p(a|c)$

The solution of my professor looks like this:

Let's say $A$ and $B$ are two dice rolls. $C=A+B$ is the sum of these dice rolls. $A$ and $B$ are independent so that, $p(a|b)=p(a)$.
When we observe $C$ the two become dependent. E.g. if we observe $C = 3$, then $p(A = 1) = 1/2$ and $p(A = 2) = 1/2$. However, if we observe $B = 2$, then $p(A = 1|B =
2) = 1$.

Can someone explain this to me? How can i create a calculatory example based on his solution? I know that $P(A)=P(B)=\frac{1}{6}$, but what is the value of $P(C)$? Is it valid to look at the value of just $P(C)$, or shouldn't i only be able to calculate the probability of specific values of $k$ for $C$ (e.g. $P(C=1)$)? And if the last statement is correct, why can i make the generalization in the case of $P(A)$ or $P(B)$?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have a look at the second answer of TooTone https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/67318/definition-of-conditional-probability-with-multiple-conditions

Comment: I understood it now, thanks for the answer. It's really fascinating how the events can become dependent after knowing C. Crazy stuff!